# bash: ./test.sh./folder: No such file or directory

Tags: bash, shell

> I am trying to read path from input but it gives error that there is no such a directory or file. input is ./test.sh./path ...

```
#!/bin/bash
var=$0
var1=$1
echo $var
echo $var1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a whitespace between filename and argument.

```
./test.sh ./path
```